# Apply `:mkview` to all open tabs at exit from Vim

Tags: autocmd, folding, tabbed-user-interface

I use Vim from the CLI and use tabs rather than buffers (as I understand the terminology). I may or may not open multiple files using the `-p` option, but end up with a few tabs open at once. If I remember to do so, I'll run `:mkview` on a tab when I've made changes that matter (usually folding). When I open a file I do `:loadview` to get back to what I had. The `au BufWinEnter ?* silent loadview` command, if understood, will load the view whenever I open the file, saving my keystrokes. Similarly `au BufWinLeave ?* mkview` *should* save the status when I close the file. However, if I have not manually done `:mkview` on a tab with folding changes and exit with `:qa` only the folding for the current tab is saved, all others remain the way they were at the last manual `:mkview`.

The only clue to the issue, and not a solution, is in the docs on `h: BufWinLeave` which has:

> When exiting and v:dying is 2 or more this event is not triggered.

It is possible that using sessions might help, except that I seldom have the same set of files open that I will want to open the next time.

So, how can I get all open tabs to save their state when I do a full exit?

Comment: Did you look at `:h v:dying`. That's not going to be the problem under any normal circumstances. Personally  I'd try various other "Leave" and "Unload" events for buffers and tabs (after reading the docs for each to make sure there are no reasons to disqualify it)...see if I had any better luck with those.

Comment: Ok, `v:dying` isn't the source of the problem. I'm new enough to power-using Vim that the solution escapes me. The help for `:tabnew` shows the sequence of triggered events when called. Is there a similar sequence somewhere for the events triggered for `:qa` or `:xa`?

Comment: @BLayer In chasing down events, I think the data layout is `vim` can have tab-pages, which can have windows, which can display a buffer. Correct?

Comment: Yes, tabs contain one or more windows each of which displays one buffer.

Comment: I wish I had more references, but auto-creating and loading views can have unwanted and hard-to-debug effects when some preference saved from the view invisibly overwrites one you’re trying to use.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Assuming I'm willing to take the risks, and put forth the effort to debug such effects once they appear, is the a way, short of a script to walk through the tabs, to accomplish my goal?

Comment: I think `:tabdo windo mkview` or similar would work? I think I’ve seen people manage a view for each window or buffer with two short autocommands, but idk how it interacts with tabs? If you want to try sessions, which I think are superior, you’ll probably like tpope/obsession.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Awesome: `au ExitPre ?* tabdo windo mkview` does as intended. Make it an answer and I'll accept. Sessions are out, as noted above, because they carry more than I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments,

```
autocmd ExitPre ?* tabdo windo mkview
```

should do it. The event `VimLeavePre` may be better.

I confess I’m not sure why the pattern is `?*` on this one.

Also, don’t forget to `augroup`.

Comment: The pattern `*` matches anything, including nothing. Using `?*` matches anything which _is_ something. The end result is the the command will not be executed when Vim is started without a file. With the pattern `*` an error, `E32: Ni file name` is generated when opening Vim w/o a file. Other than habit the `?` is pointless in the exit pattern, however. Some testing turned out to show that `VimLeavePre` is a better trigger event, in my work-flow anyway.

Comment: @Chindraba cool, thanks! I’ll edit more in when I get to a keyboard :)

Comment: `ExitPre` does work, it just makes some things not fit _my_ habits as well as `VimLeavePre` does.